# DataFrame filter on date

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Scala DataFrame (df) with a column of type date

```
dt:date
column1:string
```

I'm attempting to filter it to get only the records with dt greater or equal to a date which comes in the String format.

The code below seems to work but is it the "proper" way of doing it or should the string be explicitly converted to Date?

```
df.where($"dt" >= "2011-01-01")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Achyuth  rightly suggested to always convert to the date column of a dataframe.

```
df.where($"dt" >= "2011-01-01")
```

Gives the following query plan

```
+- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(dt#) && (cast(dt#as string) >= 2011-01-01))
```

Whereas

```
.where($"dt" >= lit(my_date_string).cast("timestamp"))
```

Does

```
 Filter (isnotnull(dt#) && (cast(dt#as timestamp) >= 1514764800000000))
```

Answer (score 3):

It would be good to convert your string to data format of the column of dataframe.

So when user sends wrong input it will validate up-front. Instead of failing at this operation.

Comment: Absolutely. But what I'm trying to understand here is whether, in my example, Spark implicitly converts date column to string or a string value to date.

Comment: It will convert string to date

Comment: Thanks for your input @Achyuth. I used to think the same but spark logs suggest otherwise: `== Optimized Logical Plan ==
GlobalLimit 
+- LocalLimit 
   +- Filter (isnotnull(dt#) && (cast(dt#as string) >= 2011-01-01))`